# windows batch file - Date replacement

Tags: windows, batch-file

Trying to copy 2 files from a remote server drive.. Need to replace the current date, month and year in the file name.

```
File1 : plugin_229_InventoryService-2017-08-11.log  (current day)

File2: plugin_229_InventoryService-2017-08-10.log  (previous day)
```

---

```
echo off
cls

::: Begin set date

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/-. " %%i in ('date /t') do (call :set_date %%i %%j %%k %%l)
goto :end_set_date

:set_date
if "%1:~0,1%" gtr "9" shift
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%m in ('echo,^|date') do (set %%m=%1&set %%n=%2&set %%o=%3)
goto :eof

:end_set_date
::: End set date

echo day in 'DD' format is %dd%; month in 'MM' format is %mm%; year in 'YYYY' format is %yy%

COPY "\\20.137.181.232\d$\Program Files\folder1\folder2\.folder3\folder4\folder5\channels\plugin_229_InventoryService-%yy%-%mm%-%dd%.log"  "D:\Folder\Master_232\"
COPY "\\20.137.181.232\d$\Program Files\folder1\folder2\.folder3\folder4\folder5\channels\plugin_229_InventoryService-%yy%-%mm%-(%dd%-1).log"  "D:\TDG\Master_232\"
```

---

Error in Output:

> day in 'DD' format is 11; month in 'MM' format is 08; year in 'YYYY'
>   format is 2 017
>
> The system cannot find the file specified. The system cannot find the
>   file specified.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

I'd not use locale/user settings dependent date/time variables but Powershell for the date calculations.

```
@echo off
cls
For /f %%T in ('powershell -NoP -C "get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd"') Do Set ToDay=%%T
For /f %%Y in ('powershell -NoP -C "(get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString(\"yyyy-MM-dd\")"') Do Set Yesterday=%%Y
Echo Today     : %ToDay%
Echo Yesterday : %Yesterday%
Set "RemotePath=\\20.137.181.232\d$\Program Files\folder1\folder2\.folder3\folder4\folder5\channels"
Echo COPY "%RemotePath%\plugin_229_InventoryService-%ToDay%.log"  "D:\Folder\Master_232\"
Echo COPY "%RemotePath%\plugin_229_InventoryService-%YesterDay%.log" "D:\TDG\Master_232\"
```

The copy commands are only echoed for testing purposes,
if the output looks OK remove the echo.

Sample output:

```
Today     : 2017-08-12
Yesterday : 2017-08-11
COPY "\\20.137.181.232\d$\Program Files\folder1\folder2\.folder3\folder4\folder5\channels\plugin_229_InventoryService-2017-08-12.log"  "D:\Folder\Master_232\"
COPY "\\20.137.181.232\d$\Program Files\folder1\folder2\.folder3\folder4\folder5\channels\plugin_229_InventoryService-2017-08-11.log" "D:\TDG\Master_232\"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
COPY "\\20.137.181.232\d$\Program Files\folder1\folder2\.folder3\folder4\folder5\channels\plugin_229_InventoryService-%yy%-%mm%-(%dd%-1).log"  "D:\TDG\Master_232\"
```

Your problem here is that `(%dd%-1)` is interpreted literally. batch stores all of its variables as strings, although the `set/a` command reads a string and writes a string according to the formula involved.

So the name of the source file would be `...-08-(11-1).log` unlikely to exist...

You would need to use `set/a` to do the calculation and assign the output to another variable.

```
set /a yesterday=dd-1
```

(set /d does not need `%dd%` - it can handle `dd`)

*BUT* be careful. The day-before-yesterday would become `9` by that calculation, which is not the same as `09`. Equally, the day before *that* would involve `dd`=09 and since batch regards a string which starts `0` as being an OCTAL string, calculating `dd`-1 would generate an error.

The usual workaround is to use batch's string-based architecture.

```
set /a yesterday=1%dd%-1
```

will generate a number `130`..`100`. If you take the last 2 characters of this, you have a convenient leading `0` as necessary, so you'd use `%yesterday:~-2%` for the filename.

And - well, the same argument goes for month, which you'll need if `dd=01`.

Then all you need is to work out the fixes for January.

Oh - and leap-years. And remember months may be 28, 29, 30 or 31 days long...

All of which *can* be done, with enough effort - but at least the reason for the `file not found` is revealed.